# Regular expression for two decimal points

Tags: java, android, regex

I want Regexp for value range between 8 to 36 and upto two decimal points...
valid values are:

```
8.5
9.56
10.69
35.9
```

Invalid are

```
123
5.9866
```

Here is my regexp..

```
([8-9]|[1-2][0-9]|(3[0-6]))|(([8-9]|[1-2][0-9]|(3[0-5]))(.[0-9][0-9]?)?)
```

but it is accepting 
1234 
8799

plz help me....

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex to match up to `36.99`:

```
^([89]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN8oP0/1)

To match up to 36 only use this regex (thanks to @Croises):

```
^(?:([89]|[12][0-9]|3[0-5])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|36)$
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans..but \ is not allowed in android..if you can give any other suggestion,it would be very helpful for me...thank you

Comment: In Java code you need to use: `^([89]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6])(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: This will accept 36.23 as well.small modification needed

Comment: Yes it will allow up to `36.99` is that okay with your @bhagyasripatel?

Comment: Or, like that for 35.99 and 36: `^(?:([89]|[12][0-9]|3[0-5])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|36)$` test: [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/bN8oP0/3)

Comment: Thanks @Croises, yes that will definitely work for `35.99` (updated)

Answer (score 0):

What about -

```
(^0*(?:[12][0-9]|[89]|3[0-5])+(\.\d{1,2})?$)|^0*36$
```

Comment: Work with `09.34` and with `0000009.34`

Comment: Is it not the requirement? there is no restriction on leading zero.

Comment: If this is the reason for down vote, then I'm sorry, I'm not convinced.

Comment: No, the reason is because it's not `[8-9]` but `[89]`, not `[3]` but `3`, like anubhava do !

Answer (score -1):

The other way of getting it.

```
^([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-6]{1}|[8-9]{1})(\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Matches

> 8.5 
>   9.56
>   10.69
>   35.9 
>  
>   26
>   34.3
>   36.45